# Angular 2 ngIf for nested component

Tags: angular, angular2-directives

I just learning angular2 and have issue with understanding of ngIf behaviour for nested components. I have 2 modules:

ProfileModule

```
import {NgModule} from "@angular/core";
import {ProfileDetailComponent} from "./profile-detail/profile-detail.component";
import {ProfileService} from "./profile.service";
import {SharedModule} from "../shared/shared.module";
import {ProfileCareerListComponent} from "./profile-career-list/profile-    career-list.component";
import {ProfileCareerDetailComponent} from "./profile-career-detail/profile-career-detail.component";

@NgModule({
    imports: [
        SharedModule
    ],
    declarations: [
        ProfileDetailComponent,
        ProfileCareerListComponent,
        ProfileCareerDetailComponent
    ],
    exports:[
        SharedModule
    ],
    providers:[
        ProfileService
    ]
})
export class ProfileModule{}
```

SharedModule:

```
import {NgModule} from "@angular/core";
import {CommonModule} from "@angular/common";
import {FormsModule} from "@angular/forms";

@NgModule({
    declarations:[
        DateDiffPipe
    ],
    imports:[
        CommonModule
    ],
    exports:[
        CommonModule,
        FormsModule
    ]
})
export class SharedModule{}
```

And I have 3 components declared in ProfileModule.

ProfileDetailComponent contains code for represent ProfileCareerListComponent:

```
...
<div class="panel-body">
    <sn-career-list></sn-career-list>
</div>
...
```

ProfileCareerListComponent contains code for representing ProfileCareerDetailComponent:

```
<div *ngIf="careerList"> /* this ngIf is work */
    <sn-career-detail *ngFor="let item of careerList" [career]="item"></sn-career-detail>
</div>
```

ProfileCareerDetailComponent contains ngIf directive, but it doesn't work:

```
...
<small *ngIf="career.RetirementDate"> - {{career.RetirementDate | date:'MMMM y'}}</small>
...
```

when I tried to start this code, I've got error:

```
Can't bind to 'ngif' since it isn't a known property of 'small'. (" *ngIf="career.RetirementDate"> - {{career.RetirementDate | date:'MMMM y'}}</small>
```

How should I import/export SharedModule with exported CommonModule for using ngIf in ProfileCareerDetailComponent? Maybe I must import something else in another modules? Or is it impossible?

Comment: Does it work if you add `CommonModule` to `imports` of `ProfileModule`? I'm not saying it's necessary. Just curious whether this fixes it. I think it should work as you have it currently.

Comment: @GünterZöchbauer I tried it, but it doesn't work

Comment: Interesting. Can you reproduce in a Plunker?

Comment: Yes, I going to do it

Comment: @GünterZöchbauer it was stupid error. At the second line of code I used 'ngif' instead ngIf. I fixed it ) I don't know, why I didn't read exception word by word ))

Comment: I wondered about the error message because I couldn't find it lowercase in your code.